# Converting array of javascript objects to key-value pairs of arrays based on property using ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

Lets say I have the following array of objects:

```
myArray = [
  {name: 'First', parent: 1, delta: 2},
  {name: 'Second', parent: 1, delta: 1},
  {name: 'Third', parent: 2, delta: 1}
];
```

I would like to convert this array to an object, with keys for the parent, and values of the objects.  e.g.:

```
result = {
  1: [
       {name: 'First', parent: 1, delta: 2},
       {name: 'Second', parent: 1, delta: 1}
     ],
  2: [
       {name: 'Third', parent: 2, delta: 1}
     ]
}
```

I can do this using a `forEach`, or nested loops, but am wondering if there is a way using ES6 syntax to do this a bit more concise/inline, which would allow me to do things like sort on `delta`, etc.

Comment: This is called "grouping".

Comment: When deciding which method to use, you might [consider the performance](https://jsperf.com/spread-vs-plain/1) of the different approaches and ponder that less code is rarely a good reason, of itself, to use a particular algorithm. The plain if..else method is nearly 10 times faster than the one using spread and concat, and twice as fast as the concat method. And you might also consider that if..else is also very much easier to read and maintain for inexperienced coders (who are most likely to do such tasks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve this

```js
var myArray = [
  {name: 'First', parent: 1, delta: 2},
  {name: 'Second', parent: 1, delta: 1},
  {name: 'Third', parent: 2, delta: 1}
];

var result = myArray.reduce((o,d) =>
             (
               o[d.parent] = (o[d.parent] || []).concat(d)
               , o
             )
             , {})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for that:

```js
let myArray = [{
    name: 'First',
    parent: 1,
    delta: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Second',
    parent: 1,
    delta: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Third',
    parent: 2,
    delta: 1
  }
];
var res = myArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (acc[item.parent]) {
    acc[item.parent].push(item);
  } else {
    acc[item.parent] = [item];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = [
  {name: 'First', parent: 1, delta: 2},
  {name: 'Second', parent: 1, delta: 1},
  {name: 'Third', parent: 2, delta: 1}
];

console.log(myArray.reduce((acc, val)=>({...acc, [val.parent]: (acc[val.parent] || []).concat(val)}), {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const result = myArray.reduce((result, el) => {
  if (result[el.parent]) result[el.parent].push(el);
  else result[el.parent] = [el];
  return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: Don't for get to return *result*, otherwise this will error after the first iteration (the callback passes *undefined* as the accumulator). ;-)